# Excel: Standard deviation, ignoring #NA and blanks in the range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, standard-deviation

I want to calculate the standard deviation with STDDEV.P for a range, but I want to ignore #NA and blank cells.

#NA and blanks should NOT be included in the calculation as 0.

I've reached this solution for ignoring #NA:

```
=STDEV.P(IF(NOT(ISERROR(Trade!AI5:AI154));Trade!AI5:AI154))
```

How do I ignore blank cells as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached a conclusion myself, using ISNUMBER():

```
=STDEV.P(IF(ISNUMBER(Trade!AI5:AI154);Trade!AI5:AI154))
```